# maven settings.xml properties are not seen in pom

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

i have in settings.xml following config

```
<profile>
<properties>
<nexus.host>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories</nexus.host>
</properties>
</profile>
```

this profile is set as active.

its used in distribution management section of pom

```
<distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>my-snapshots</id>
            <name>my snapshots</name>
            <url>${nexus.path}/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>my-releases</id>
            <name>my releases</name>
            <url>${nexus.path}/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

this works when i run it on local machine, but when the job is executed on jenkins it fails with 
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

> [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer
>   com.myapp:sample:pom:1.1.0 from ${nexus.path}/releases was cached in
>   the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of my-releases has elapsed or updates are forced.
>   Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.myapp:sample:pom:1.1.0
>   from/to my-releases (${nexus.path}/releases): Cannot access
>   ${nexus.path}/releases with type default using the available connector
>   factories: WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory and 'parent.relativePath'
>   points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 13

unable to identify the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the past. To resolve this in Jenkins you will need to set the Maven argument so it can find the location of your settings.xml.

You will need to have the settings.xml in the application resources so Jenkins can find it.

To set the argument(In Jenkins, it should be under Goals and options):

```
-s src/main/resources/settings.xml
```

However in my instance the Jenkins administrators provided a separate version of maven so the application will have the needed settings.xml and there was no need to provide our own custom settings.xml.

On a side note, you might want to contact the Jenkins Administrators to ensure that they have implemented the proper configurations so Jenkins will be able to deploy the produced artifacts to the repository under the id you have specified.